# Google tag scripts are automatically getting removed from the Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2.4, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have added the `gtag` script in the `Html Head` section under the `scripts and style sheets`

[image]

after saving it, I am not able to see it in the head section.

[image]

only the commented part is appearing. The rest is disappeared. Can anyone help me to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Flush your cache `bin/magento cache:flush`
2. Edit the correct position for `Html Head > Scripts and style sheets`
   There are three similar places to edit.
   Usually the bottom one is the correct one.

[image]